# Android Widget Dynamically changes Shape Drawable

Tags: android, dynamic, drawable

I have widget that use LinearLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/back_rounded_black"
>
```

And This is content of back_rounded_black

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
<solid android:color="#000000" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <gradient android:startColor="#ff777777" android:endColor="#ff000000" android:angle="270" />  
</shape>
```

Now, I want to let user change any of these, such as the corner radius, solid color, stroke color, gradient color, etc via SharedPreferences.

How to pass the user parameter value into drawables on RemoteView?